# Why is the Onenote app completely hanging?

Tags: ios, performance, ipad, onenote

I have been using Onenote for some time and quite enjoyed it. Although now, I am faced with a strange problem. Onenote is refusing to respond to the right side of the keyboard. It's not one of those bugs that I can work around either. It's becoming very difficult to use.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean that all keys on the right side of the keyboard don't respond? Both in typing text and for shortcuts?

Comment: Does the keyboard work correctly in every other app but Onenote?

Comment: Yeah, it works in every other app except OneNote. I don't have any shortcuts in my iPad but it isn't able to type in OneNote.

Comment: Just out of curiosity....does the problem manifest when using an external keyboard?

Comment: Hey, sorry I hadn't checked in months. I don't have an external keyboards. So, the next best thing is using a third party keyboard. The problem doesn't happen with third party keyboard for some time in one orientation. ( It doesn't work if you flip the iPad). And, even that is until a time period, after which the app needs to be closed and restarted.